# КАК не отображать блок ACF на странице если он не заполнен в админке wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно не отображать блок на странице если он не заполнен в админке. Вот код, что я делаю не правильно, спасибо. ?!

```
 <?php if(get_field('seo-two-block')) { ?>
<section class="seo__text two_col">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                $seoBlock = get_field('seo-two-block');
                if( !empty($seoBlock) ) : {
                    echo $seoBlock;
                } ?>
                    <div class="section__title">
                        <h3><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-title']; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-subtitle']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="seo__left column">
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-left']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="seo__right column">
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-right']; ?></p>
                    </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

У Вас проверка не срабатывает, т.к. значение массив.

Удаляем из массива пустые элементы. Проверяем перед показом блока - не пустой массив

```
<?php $seoBlock = get_field('seo-two-block'); ?>

<?php $seoBlock = array_filter($seoBlock, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; }); ?>

<?php if(sizeof($seoBlock)) { ?>
<section class="seo__text two_col">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                    <?php if (isset($seoBlock['seo-block-title']) || isset($seoBlock['seo-block-subtitle'])) : ?>
                    <div class="section__title">
                    
                        <?php if (isset($seoBlock['seo-block-title'])) : ?>
                        <h3><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-title']; ?></h3>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (isset($seoBlock['seo-block-subtitle'])) : ?>
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-subtitle']; ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($seoBlock['seo-block-left'])) : ?>
                    <div class="seo__left column">
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-left']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($seoBlock['seo-block-right'])) : ?>
                    <div class="seo__right column">
                        <p><?php echo $seoBlock['seo-block-right']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.

Comment: Можете отметить ответ как правильный ?

Comment: а зачем столько кода? ! empty() мало?

Comment: @WPPunk если значение будет вида array('seo-block-title'=>'', 'seo-block-subtitle' => '', 'seo-block-right' => '', 'seo-block-left' => ''), то !empty() вернет true. собственно в коде вопроса от автора используется проверка на empty

Comment: Ну это же говнокод